# Serverless HTTP API - serverless-domain-manager Error: Failed to find a stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm trying to deploy the basic serverless express api example - https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/v2/aws-node-express-api with a custom domain. It uses `HTTP Api` instead of the older REST API gateway.
The domain has been set up successfully, certificate in place etc. but when I run `serverless deploy` it throws an error:

```
Error: Unable to setup base domain mappings for mycustom.domain.name
```

Adding SLS_DEBUG revealed:

```
Service Information
-------------------
service: my-service-name
stage: staging
region: us-east-1
stack: my-service-name-staging
resources: 11
api keys:
  None
endpoints:
  ANY - https://123323.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
functions:
  api: my-service-name-staging-api
layers:
  None
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 400 1.296s 0 retries] describeStackResource({
  LogicalResourceId: 'ApiGatewayRestApi',
  StackName: 'my-service-name-staging'
})
Serverless: [AWS cloudformation 200 1.592s 0 retries] describeStacks({})
Serverless Domain Manager: Error: mycustom.domain.name:  Error: Failed to find a stack my-service-name-staging

Serverless Domain Manager: Error: mycustom.domain.name:  Error: Failed to find CloudFormation resources for mycustom.domain.name
```

Clearly the stack exists, but serverless domain manager can't find it. Can I not use custom domain via serverless-domain-manager with HTTP api?? The documentation only shows a [manual way](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api/#custom-domains) to do this.. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to answer 100% without seeing your configuration, but are you sure you've specified `apiType: http` in your `customDomain` config section? If not, it defaults to `rest`. Setting it to `http` should resolve your problem.

Comment: Hey, I did set the `apiType: http` and it did not work still. I eventually ended up using a standard `rest` api and the same config worked. I found that others were facing this issue with the `http` api as well - https://github.com/amplify-education/serverless-domain-manager/issues/465

Answer (score 2):

Since your complete serverless.yml is not here, I guess you are using the default one. I had the same issue, and here is my solution.
This is probably the customDomain conf in your .yml file:

```
customDomain:
    domainName: sub.domain.com
    certificateName: '*.domain.com'
    basePath: ${sls:stage}
    stage: ${sls:stage} 
    createRoute53Record: true
```

The only thing you need to do is add these two attributes to convert your domain from edge to regional:

```
  customDomain:
    domainName: sub.domain.com
    certificateName: '*.domain.com'
    basePath: ${sls:stage}
    stage: ${sls:stage} 
    createRoute53Record: true
    endpointType: regional <-- New Attribute (default is edge)
    apiType: http <-- New Attribute (default is rest)
```

Remember, if you already have run the `sls create_domain` command (with the previous serverless.yml configuration), you might face this error:

```
Error:
Error: Unable to setup base domain mappings for 'sub.domain.com':
Unable to create base path mapping for 'sub.domain.com':
Only REGIONAL domain names can be managed through the API Gateway V2 API. For EDGE domain names, please use the API Gateway V1 API. Also note that only REST APIs can be attached to EDGE domain names.
```

The reason for this error is that you have created an edge domain with the previous configuration, and now, the deployment wants to use it as a regional domain. To solve this error, just delete the domain with `sls delete_domain` and then rerun the `sls create_domain` command. I will automatically create the new records for you.

Comment: Thanks @Leo I'll give this a try over the weekend and update if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to 6.4.3 solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Python wsgi app and in my case, this solved the issue:

```yaml
    
custom:
  wsgi:
    app: api.app
  customDomain:
    basePath: ${opt:stage}
    domainName: mydomain.name.com
    stage: ${opt:stage}
    createRoute53Record: true
    createRoute53IPv6Record: true
    endpointType: 'regional'
    securityPolicy: tls_1_2
    autoDomain: true
```

without specifying `http:`

source:
https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-wsgi